# React JS web app shows "undefined" pop up Error message when the page is not in use for few minutes or if there is no internet connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue and i don't even know where should I start the investigation.
I have a website that based on Flask and react, i fetch stock prices from my backend every minute and it seems like when the webpage is not able to fetch the stock prices from the backend, i'm getting the attached popup message and the page got stuck.
I need to close the webpage in order to start use it again.

Can you please give me some direction, what can be the root cause?.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G03BI.png)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find in the project all lines of code that execute `alert(`. You'll be able to find the place of a code that executes `alert` if there is some backend's issue.

Comment: I guess you are talking on these lines:
else if(ret['data'].result === 'fail'){
                                alert(ret['data'].message);
                              }
Am i right? can i just delete those  alert( lines?

Comment: @pythonist I know nothing about your project, and about this logic :) So I can't say, can you just remove this line or not.

I believe the server returns result with `fail` because of some error. So you should retrieve error's message from response and notify users about that.